# Another PHP Contact Form not Sending

Tags: php, html, forms, post, contact-form

I have made a contact.php file with a very simple php email submit script and form.  The script and form are in the same file.  For the life of me, I cannot get it to send email on submit. If I remove the if statement for isset($_POST['submit'], then it will of course automatically send mail when the page loads, which I do receive. But as soon as I set it up to only work on submit, I do not receive the email.  Right now I am using a gmail account, but I won't be later.  I am not an expert at php, but from researching, this seems like a pretty straightforward script.  I have tried many different variations, and I just want to keep this simple for now. My form is HTML5 compliant and I am using HTML5 to validate before sending, so right now I don't need any type of validation.  I am not sure why this will not send.  I have tried different headers.  I have searched stackoverflow as much as I can to see if there is any solution, which I have tried several, but I still cannot get this to send.

contact.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $to = 'someone@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Contact Form Submission';
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  $website = $_POST['website'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $header .= "From: ". $email ."\r\n";
  $header .= "Reply-To: ". $email ."\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset= utf-8 \r\n";

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Telephone: $telephone\n Website: $website\n 
  Message:\n $message";

  if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
  {
    echo 'Thank you! Your message has been sent. We will try to contact you within one 
    business day.';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'There was an error with your submission. Please try again.';
  }
}
?>

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>

    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" required>

    <label>Telephone</label>
    <input name="telephone" type="tel" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required>

    <label>Website (Optional)</label>
    <input name="website" type="url" placeholder="http://www.yoursite.com">
</div>

<div>
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type what you want here" required></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name"submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
</div>

<div class="call">
    <span>Or call us at (555) 555-5555</span>
</div>
</form>
```

I have also tried to take out the action on the form tag since it is calling the script from the same file, and I have tried using `<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>`.  I am sure this is something simple I am missing, but I am really wasting hours of time trying to figure this out. Again, it does send mail if I remove the if statement checking for $_POST['submit'], so I know it will send. But it is like my submit input is not right with the script, or something. Not sure.

Comment: To be sure that after submit, the `if` is reached, temporarily do: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))
die('here');`
and tell us the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code (which is wrong) :

```
<input id="submit" name"submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
```

You had **`name"submit"`** instead of **`name` `=` `"submit"`**

---

But the right code is:

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
```

Comment: Alright, I feel extra stupid now. I was changing the name field in my input tag earlier when I was trying to figure out what the issue was, and must of left out the = when I changed it back. Probably fixed my issues and didn't know it because of this. Thank you. Like I said, looked at this forever. Just need another set of eyes.

Comment: Can exactly feel you! Hope to no more have such headaches! `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the condition to send the email by checking if all of your required parameters are setted in the post request.

Answer (score 1):

give it a try!

if($_POST['submit'] == 'Send Message'){

//..... send

}